# gremlin clone a node and its edges

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases, gremlin, amazon-neptune

Does gremlin provide the ability to clone a vertex for instance
`v1->v2, v1->v3, v1->v4` how can I simply and efficiently create a new vertex `v5` that also has edges that point to `v2, v3, v4` (the same places that `v1's` edges point to) without have to explicitly set them and instead saying something like `g.createV(v1).clone(v2)`.

Note that I am using the AWS Neptune version of gremlin, solution must be compatible with that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A `clone` step doesn't exist (yet), but it can be solved with a single query.

Let's start with some sample data:

```
gremlin> g = TinkerFactory.createModern().traversal()
==>graphtraversalsource[tinkergraph[vertices:6 edges:6], standard]
gremlin> g.V(4).valueMap(true)                                   // the vertex to be cloned
==>[label:person,name:[josh],age:[32],id:4]
gremlin> g.V(4).outE().map(union(identity(), valueMap()).fold()) // all out-edges
==>[e[10][4-created->5],[weight:1.0]]
==>[e[11][4-created->3],[weight:0.4]]
gremlin> g.V(4).inE().map(union(identity(), valueMap()).fold())  // all in-edges
==>[e[8][1-knows->4],[weight:1.0]]
```

Now the query to clone the vertex might look a bit scary at a first glance, but it's really just the same pattern over and over again - jumping between the original and the clone to copy the properties:

```
g.V(4).as('source').
  addV().
    property(label, select('source').label()).as('clone').
  sideEffect(                                                // copy vertex properties
    select('source').properties().as('p').
    select('clone').
      property(select('p').key(), select('p').value())).
  sideEffect(                                                // copy out-edges
    select('source').outE().as('e').
    select('clone').
    addE(select('e').label()).as('eclone').
      to(select('e').inV()).
    select('e').properties().as('p').                        // copy out-edge properties
    select('eclone').
      property(select('p').key(), select('p').value())).
  sideEffect(                                                // copy in-edges
    select('source').inE().as('e').
    select('clone').
    addE(select('e').label()).as('eclone').
      from(select('e').outV()).
    select('e').properties().as('p').                        // copy in-edge properties
    select('eclone').
      property(select('p').key(), select('p').value()))
```

And in action it looks like this:

```
gremlin> g.V(4).as('source').
......1>   addV().
......2>     property(label, select('source').label()).as('clone').
......3>   sideEffect(
......4>     select('source').properties().as('p').
......5>     select('clone').
......6>       property(select('p').key(), select('p').value())).
......7>   sideEffect(
......8>     select('source').outE().as('e').
......9>     select('clone').
.....10>     addE(select('e').label()).as('eclone').
.....11>       to(select('e').inV()).
.....12>     select('e').properties().as('p').
.....13>     select('eclone').
.....14>       property(select('p').key(), select('p').value())).
.....15>   sideEffect(
.....16>     select('source').inE().as('e').
.....17>     select('clone').
.....18>     addE(select('e').label()).as('eclone').
.....19>       from(select('e').outV()).
.....20>     select('e').properties().as('p').
.....21>     select('eclone').
.....22>       property(select('p').key(), select('p').value()))
==>v[13]
gremlin> g.V(13).valueMap(true)                                   // the cloned vertex
==>[label:person,name:[josh],age:[32],id:13]
gremlin> g.V(13).outE().map(union(identity(), valueMap()).fold()) // all cloned out-edges
==>[e[16][13-created->5],[weight:1.0]]
==>[e[17][13-created->3],[weight:0.4]]
gremlin> g.V(13).inE().map(union(identity(), valueMap()).fold())  // all cloned in-edges
==>[e[18][1-knows->13],[weight:1.0]]
```

**UPDATE**

Paging support is a little tricky. Let me split this whole thing into a 3-step process. I will use edge ids as the sort criterion and to identify the last processed edge (this might not work in Neptune, but you can use a unique sortable property instead).

```
// clone the vertex with its properties
clone = g.V(4).as('source').
  addV().
    property(label, select('source').label()).as('clone').
  sideEffect(
    select('source').properties().as('p').
    select('clone').
      property(select('p').key(), select('p').value())).next()

// clone out-edges
pageSize = 1
lastId = -1
while (true) {
  t = g.V(4).as('source').
    outE().hasId(gt(lastId)).
    order().by(id).limit(pageSize).as('e').
    group('x').
      by(constant('lastId')).
      by(id()).
    V(clone).
    addE(select('e').label()).as('eclone').
      to(select('e').inV()).
    sideEffect(
      select('e').properties().as('p').
      select('eclone').
        property(select('p').key(), select('p').value())).
    count()
  if (t.next() != pageSize)
    break
  lastId = t.getSideEffects().get('x').get('lastId')
}

// clone in-edges
lastId = -1
while (true) {
  t = g.V(4).as('source').
    inE().hasId(gt(lastId)).
    order().by(id).limit(pageSize).as('e').
    group('x').
      by(constant('lastId')).
      by(id()).
    V(clone).
    addE(select('e').label()).as('eclone').
      from(select('e').inV()).
    sideEffect(
      select('e').properties().as('p').
      select('eclone').
        property(select('p').key(), select('p').value())).
    count()
  if (t.next() != pageSize)
    break
  lastId = t.getSideEffects().get('x').get('lastId')
}
```

I don't know if Neptune allows you to execute full scripts - if not, you'll need to execute the outer while loops in you application's code.

Comment: How well would you say this scales and/or what limits would this query have? If there were 1,000,000 outgoing/incoming edges would this still work? Will this work with AWS Neptune API?

Comment: I think it ultimately depends on the graph db you're using. However, having that many incident edges is generally seen as a bad graph model.

Comment: it seems like AWS Neptune is limiting this query to only 999 edges, is there a way to paginate this query such that I can run it for nodes with larger number of edges?

Comment: You'll need a guaranteed sort order and a unique property on your edges, then it might work. I'll try to put something together later tonight, perhaps just extend the previous example using a page size of 1.

Comment: you are too kind! Embarrassingly I believe I was mistaken, I must have had a typo in my latest query because I just cloned a node with 100,000 outgoing edges on the smallest Neptune instance type and it was successful and took under a minute. Though its not urgent, pagination would be nice, yes I'll have guaranteed ordering of my node id's v0 - v100000. PS my graph model has *lots* of incoming edges, but not many outgoing edges (which is what I believe you meant be incident edges).

Comment: Incident edges refer to both - incoming and outgoing edges. For the paging you need a unique (sortable) identifier/property on the edges, not on the vertices. I'll post an update in a few minutes.

Comment: Hi @DanielKuppitz, I tried the query with Azure CosmosDb and I am getting an error says <Gremlin Query Compilation Error: Unable to bind to method 'property', with arguments of type: (GraphTraversal,GraphTraversal)>. If I change this <select('source').properties().as('p').
    select('clone').
      property(select('p').key(), select('p').value())> to a constant key and value it works. Any Idea how to solve this?

Comment: I guess you'll have to wait for CosmosDB to catch up with the latest Gremlin features.