# Clone an Edge and target vertex in Cosmos Gremlin

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, gremlin

```
g.AddV('test').property('id','1').property('name','test 1')
g.AddV('test').property('id','2').property('name','test 2')

g.V('1').AddE('owns').to(g.AddV('another').property('id','3'))
```

Is there any way i can clone this `owns` edge and it's target `another` vertex of `test 1` with all properties into  `test 2` vertex? This is just a sample data. I have vertex with at least 10 properties.

**NOTE** :  Query needs to support `cosmos db gremlin api`.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to this one is mostly presented in this other StackOverflow question which explains how to [clone a vertex and all it's edges](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51900116/1831717). Since this question is slightly different I thought I'd adapt it a bit rather this suggesting closing this as a duplicate.

```
gremlin> g.V().has('test','name','test 1').as('t1').
......1>   outE('owns').as('e').inV().as('source').
......2>   V().has('test','name','test 2').as('target').
......3>   sideEffect(       
......4>     select('source').properties().as('p').
......5>     select('target').
......6>       property(select('p').key(), select('p').value())).
......7>   sideEffect(
......8>     select('t1').
......9>     addE(select('e').label()).as('eclone').
.....10>       to(select('target')).
.....11>     select('e').properties().as('p').                        
.....12>     select('eclone').
.....13>       property(select('p').key(), select('p').value()))
==>v[3]
gremlin> g.E()
==>e[8][0-owns->6]
==>e[10][0-owns->3]
gremlin> g.V().valueMap(true)
==>[id:0,label:test,name:[test 1],id:[1]]
==>[id:3,label:test,name:[test 2],id:[3]]
==>[id:6,label:another,id:[3]]
```

Note that since labels are immutable, you are stuck with the vertex label being "another" given the way that you laid out your sample data. Also, I know it is just sample data, but note that overloading "id" isn't a good choice as it can lead to confusion with `T.id`.

Comment: Thanks. Does `sideEffect` work with cosmos gremlin api?

Comment: i thought so, but i think it is undocumented.

Comment: looks like `sideEffect` is not supported in cosmos gremlin. I am getting this error `Unable to bind to method 'sideEffect', with arguments of type:()`

Comment: hmm - sorry, i'm not sure how to do this in a single traversal without `sideEffect()`

Answer (score 0):

Execute api:  `g.V().has('name','test 1').id()`

[image]

Then try to loop the results in [java code](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/3.0.1-incubating/#_the_graph_structure) and execute the add edge api:

```
g.V(<the id of vertex loop>).AddE('owns').to(<the id of vertex 'test2'>)
```

If the vertexes of test 2 are multiple,then you could two-dimensional loop.